# Rails using modal to open a new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my rails app, I want to use modal to open a new page.

For example, in the `index.html.erb`, I have a button "New". When I click "New", a dialog would display the content in `new.html.erb`. I tried to use:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="#{new_site_path}" data-target="#myModal">New</a>
```

But it's not working, what is the best rails way to do that? Thanks.

**Updated:**

I found a way that is:

```
<%= link_to "Open modal", new_site_path, :class => "btn", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => ".bs-example-modal-lg" %>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the open dialog is include the html code in `application.html.erb` which include the navigation bar and side bar, but I don't want it, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently your modal is opening but not showing the `new.html.erb` file contents?

Comment: Yes, I think the syntax of href is not correct, but I don't know the correct one

Answer (score 1):

The link should be:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#myModal">New</a>
```

Now create a `partial` in the page where that upper `a` tag contains. Suppose, you have created `_modal_patrial.html.erb`. then `render` the partial in the current page.

on `_modal_patrial.html.erb`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   // new.html.erb contents will go here.    
</div>
```

You can see this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals) for details. 
Hope it  helps!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have found a way to solve this problem, but I meet a new problem which post on the question, can you help me? thanks

Comment: @Stephen, Your question is not clear. Could you please elaborate?